# Use systemInfo properties in Qt Framework Installer config file

Tags: xml, qt, frameworks

I want to create an installer based on Qt Framework Installer which will be compilabe with different systems. I would like to use different control scripts for every system. I am trying to achive it by changing path to it in config.xml. According to the documentation I could use `systemInfo` class with property `kernelType`. https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-systeminfo.html . My problem is that, I don't know how to use it in xml file. Other Predefined Variables are used like this `@Variable@` but with that class I cannot find the way to use this variable. I have tried for example: `@kernelType@` `@systemInfo::kernelType@ @systemInfo.kernelType@`. Does anyone has idea how it might be use. Thanks in advance

Comment: In my experience I have only ever seen this used in .qs files. My company use this framework a lot and I have never seen this done in an xml file. Why not have a separate config.xml for each os? We separate mac and windows installers into their own completely separate dirs anyway bc they need their own special stuff.

Comment: I found out that it is posible to use evironment variables in the curly bracets `{variable_name}` I am genereting installer by the python script where I defined the needed variable. Nevertheless i think it might be possible to use also in xml files.